# 'ClientScript' is not declared when calling bootstrap Modal from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I want to call Bootstrap Modal From code behind when page loads. I use below code but it throws compilation error

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowRegPopup();", true);
```

> Error:'ClientScript' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType()` change it to this

Comment: @MethodMan thanks. It worked.

Comment: if the answer fixed your issue please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change it to use the `Page`

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "ShowRegPopup();", true);
```